# Mapping takes long time for bulk data

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

When I retrieve data from SQL Server, it takes 2 minutes for bulk data  (2000000 rows) in SQL query window. But it takes long time (approximately 20 minutes or more) for mapping as a list using dapper ORM.

Is there any idea to increase the performance in mapping.

This is my code:

```
public List<T> DapperToList<T>(string SqlQuery, CommandType? CommandType = null) where T : class
{
    if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        Con.Close();

    Con.Open();

    var result = this.Con.Query<T>(SqlQuery, null, null, true, int.MaxValue, CommandType).ToList();

    Con.Close();

    return result;
}

public List<LOG_REPORTS> REPORT_LOG(DateTime? FROMDATE, DateTime? TODATE)
{
    DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();

    param.Add("@FROMDATE", FROMDATE, DbType.DateTime);
    param.Add("@TODATE", TODATE, DbType.DateTime);

    var lstt = db.DapperToList<LOG_REPORTS>("PROC_LOG_REPORTS", param, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    return lstt;
}
```

Comment: Uh... Do you _really_ need to load 2 000 000 records?

Comment: yes.some times.

Comment: And what do you do with this amount of data?

Comment: Client requested for this.Their one day transaction may come above 100000 records.So when take monthly transactions will reach at least 200000 records.

Comment: How would this data be used? raw data dump? depending on the use case, you may not even need to map it to objects? 
Loading and then processing several hundred K of instances in memory is going to be resource intense, and there's not usually a use case to do so on a system that is directly interacting with the user. If the system is not user interacting, then the 20 minutes shouldn't be a problem and there are other alternatives than mapping to 200K instances in a List

Comment: Okay.It may not be good method.But in case I need to export that huge data to excel or word ..How to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you explained in the question `var result = this.Con.Query<T>(SqlQuery,.....)` line takes 20 minutes to execute. Based on your research, 2 minutes for executing query and remaining 18 minutes for mapping.

## Solution 1: Pump paged data

Mapping such huge data will take time (and memory and processor and ...) and there is near to no scope to improve this. Consider paging on database side using `ROW_NUMBER` and pump one page at a time. As you said you are writing data to Excel; so this should not be an issue. But this will actually increase total time even though per batch time will be reduced and application will be responsive.

## Solution 2: Do NOT map

You want to write a Excel, right? then bypass Dapper and use ADO.NET. Pass `DataTable` to Excel writer module. This will be huge gain.